# Vector3 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What values should I use to assign to a Vector3? The engine keeps telling me that there's something wrong with the values that I gave in the Update function.
The codes are as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 rotation;

    void Update()
    {
        rotation += (0, 0, 45);

    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean `rotation += new Vector3(0, 0, 45);`?

Comment: Maybe you should get into some basic tutorials about general c# before jumping into Unity?

Comment: And why not simply `rotation += Vector3.forward * 45;` in this case? ;)  Also note that you definitely do **not** want to do that anyway! Currently you will rotate 45° **every frame** .. your rotation is simply going to wildly flicker around ... You rather want to use e.g. `rotation += Vector3.forward * 45 * Time.deltaTime;` in order to rotate 45° **per second**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Vector3(x,y,z)` to create a Vector3 object

```cs
Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

And to add values to the Vector3

```cs
rotation += new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

[Documentation for Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html)